# What is the Playstation Quest For Greatness?

Tags: ps3, psn, ps4

I read something today that said if you complete "The Quest for Greatness" on PS3 or PS4, you get some free PSone games.

However I can't seem to find information on what it is. I see walkthroughs, but no official explanation so far. What is the Quest for Greatness and how do I complete it?

Comment: There seems to be nothing official from Sony other than this video: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3Xp4eaFnF-o Certainly odd. Something to do with collectible cards based on knowledge of PlayStation systems.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### The Short:

Basically, QfG is a way for PlayStation to advertise an underused service of theirs by incentivizing users with free content.

### The Long:

PlayStation's official YouTube Channel released these videos concerning their Quest for Greatness (QfG):

QfG is an episodic miniquest series (1 and 2 are out and we are expecting a third and more installments). It is made to promote the almost forgotten PlayStation Home. To help bring new life to PS Home QfG offers incentives such as free games and ingame content. All QfG gameplay is free and can be reached through PlayStation home.

A PlayStation employee on the forums recently [posted about QfG2](http://community.us.playstation.com/t5/PlayStation-Home/Quest-For-Greatness-2/td-p/43070327) (including a voucher code and a walkthrough), inviting people to share their experiences on the thread.

Answer (score -3):

It is in PlayStation Home which is a free downloadable app. Here is a guide to finishing the quest. http://community.us.playstation.com/t5/PlayStation-Home/Complete-Guide-to-the-Quest-for-Greatness/td-p/42238809

Comment: Hi! Any chance you can provide some more detail here in addition to the URL? We like to ensure that answers can remain largely useful even if the link gets broken someday.